# How to get user mail id and user name from Office.js or Office API

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am working on Word , Excel and PowerPoint add-ins . I want to upload document from graphs API .Below are API  **PUT** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/**myuser@domain.subdomain.com**/drive/items/root:/filename.docx:/content and it is working fine from Postman .

My concern how I will get USER Mail Id from Word , Excel and PowerPoint add-ins as Any direct API not available .

I follow below article still  not success and getting 13006 error .

**message: "An unexpected error occurred in the client."
name: "Error occurred in the authentication request from Office."**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#register-your-add-in-with-the-microsoft-identity-platform

```
 async  getToken() { 
    var returnObject; 
    window.Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true },function (result) { 
      console.log( result); 

      if (result.status === "succeeded") {
         var token = result.value; 
         returnObject = token; 
         console.log(token)
        } else { 
          console.log("Error obtaining token", result); 
        }
         });
          return returnObject; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
async function getUserData() {
    try {
        let userTokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
        let userToken = jwt_decode(userTokenEncoded); // Using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode library.
        console.log(userToken.name); // user name
        console.log(userToken.preferred_username); // email
        console.log(userToken.oid); // user id     
    }
    catch (exception) {
        if (exception.code === 13003) {
            // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
            // Microsoft 365 Education or work account, or a Microsoft account.
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

If your add-in is loaded on an older version of Office that does not support SSO, the `getAccessToken` call will fail. For Excel, Word, and PowerPoint add-ins you will typically want to fall back to using the Microsoft identity platform. For more information, see [Authenticate with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz#authenticate-with-the-microsoft-identity-platform).

See [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) for more information.

Comment: I am using Office https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js API .

Now I am getting below error :-

OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'Preauthorization missing.', message: 'Missing grant for this add-in.', code: 13005}

For server response :- 404

https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Menifest File :

<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp" >

Comment: To be able to use the `getAccessToken` method in the code you need to authorize/register your app in Azure. Please check out the article mentioned in my post.